# IIS 7.5 with an ASP.NET application and trailing slash

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

I've a IIS 7.5 with one application configured in the "Default Website" called "demo".
The physical path of this application locates outside the folder for "Default Website". It's located at "c:\Program files\myWebsite\demo"

If I now call the IIS via http://mywebsite.com/demo/ everything works fine.
But if I miss the trailing "/" and call http://mywebsite.com/demo I get a yellow error page with "Server Error in '/demo' Application."

How can I configure my IIS to accept "demo" and "demo/"?

Thanks, Konrad

Comment: Is this an MVC application or a web application project?

Comment: Not that I've seen this before, but you can use the url rewrite 2.0 download from the web platform installer and create a rule for this. http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite

Comment: Its an MVC application. I don't want to use the Ur Rewriter, since I want to keep the installation small (the admin of the server has to redo all steps later again, and I don't want an extra-long install description). I wonder, why this not happens, when the website is physical located in the IIS website folder. Then both "demo" and "demo/" are working.